# Update con IF - SQL MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo que cambiar el valor/estado a un ENUM('0', '1') de un campo de una tabla. Lo voy a realizar con una consulta UPDATE con if incluido.

cambiar_estado.php:

```
<?php
    //Dormimos el proceso unos segundos...
    sleep(3);

    //Consulta para actualizar el estado en la tabla "usuarios_datos".
    $Sql = "UPDATE usuarios_datos if(estado = '0', SET estado = '1'), if(estado = '1', SET estado = '0') WHERE ID_OBLIGATORIO = '$_REQUEST["Id"];";
?>

<center>
    <?php 
        echo "<a href=\"javascript:cargaXML('cambiar_estado.php?Id=".$_REQUEST["Id"]."','estado".$_REQUEST["Id"]."')\">";
            echo $Sql;
        echo "</a>";
    ?>
</center>
```

> Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'if estado = 0   SET estado = 1 else if estado = 1 SET e' at
>   line 1

Comment: ¿Que significa _problema con la solución_?

Comment: Creo que la consulta no se puede hacer como lo has hecho, Esto: `if(estado = '0', SET estado = '1'), if(estado = '1', SET estado = '0')` no puede ir asi en mysql

Comment: ¿Cómo sería la posible solución?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba hacerlo asi:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE usuarios_datos 
  SET estado = IF(estado = "0", "1", "0") 
  WHERE ID_OBLIGATORIO = '.$_REQUEST['Id'];
```

**NOTA**: Te pido leas sobre [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Si. Gracias. Funciona correctamente en la SQL pero en la ejecucción del .php no, me da el siguiente fallo:
"expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING"

Comment: @omaza1990 , puede escribir aquí el query? Porque al parecer hay problemas de comillas

Comment: $Sql = 'UPDATE usuarios_datos SET estado = if(estado = '0', '1', '0') WHERE ID_OBLIGATORIO = "$_REQUEST['Id']"';
 $Res = $Clase->Query($Sql);

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, cambiando de comillas simples (') a dobles ("). Con eso debería salir andando.

Answer (score 0):

Hola buen dia puedes añadir la siguiente lógica al query.

```
UPDATE usuarios_datos    
set estado =(case estado when 1 then estado=0 when 0 then estado=1 end )
```

espero te sea de ayuda.

saludos.